# Convergence of the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^q}{e^{x^p |\sin x|^r}}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:
Study the convergence of following integral: $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^q}{e^{x^p |\sin x|^r}}$$
What I have tried:
Divided area in intervals $[\pi k ; \pi(k + 1)]$. On each interval $x^p \sim k^p; x^q \sim k^q$. Then I divided each interval in a half and used a fact that $\sin(\pi k + t) \sim t$. Thus i need to somehow estimate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{e^{k^p t^r}}dt$$ At this stage I got stuck. Could someone provide me a hint how to move forward or suggest another solution?

Comment: What are $p,q,$ and $r$?

Comment: @QC_QAOA Real numbers. I need to study what relations they should have so this integral will converge or not converge.

Comment: Any conditions on them? Positive for example or can they also be negative?

Comment: It was not given in a problem, so i don't really know. I think that in result I somehow should get something like $\frac{1}{x^{f(p,q,r)}}$ and just get some inequality on them in result